# Ansible breaks "Failed to connect to the host via scp: scp: Connection closed"

Tags: ansible

I have a strange problem regarding ansible. I use Ansible in v.2.12.10 in a python-venv. I created this venv on a windows machine and now I try to use it on my Macbook, but ansible fails with the following error:

```
PLAY [Provision all hosts] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [jumper.YYY.systems]: UNREACHABLE! => changed=false 
  msg: |-
    Failed to connect to the host via scp: scp: Connection closed
  unreachable: true
fatal: [cloud.YYY.systems]: UNREACHABLE! => changed=false 
  msg: |-
    Failed to connect to the host via scp: scp: Connection closed
  unreachable: true
```

I encounterd this issue a while ago, but I didnt pinned down the solution. I guess it was to use ansible in v.2.12 and higher, but now it fails. On my Windows Machine all works well.

ansible.cfg:

```
[defaults]
nocows = 1
vault_password_file = ./.vault_pass
ansible_managed = Ansible managed - keep your paws off! {file} last modified by {uid}
remote_user = root
host_key_checking = False
retry_files_enabled = False
stdout_callback = yaml
collections_paths = ./
library = ./
roles_path = roles/
# Keep mitogen in mind https://github.com/mitogen-hq/mitogen
# Actually not working with newer ansible releases
#strategy_plugins = mitogen/mitogen-0.3.3/ansible_mitogen/plugins/strategy/
#strategy = mitogen_linear
[ssh_connection]
scp_if_ssh = True
ssh_args = -o ForwardAgent=yes -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s
```

If I comment out `scp_if_ssh = True` it works, but I need this. And this is the same configuration as on my Windows machine, so i can't get the point why this fails.

Comment: On my Windows Machine all works well. We don't know which version of Ansible is in your Windows Machine vs your Mac nor about the version of Openssh. You might take a look at this thread  https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/78600, specially bcoca's comment.

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution! Bocca's comment and the ansible documentation at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ssh_connection.html#parameter-ssh_transfer_method solved the problem. My openssh version truely differs, my mac users 9.0. That's the cause of the problem.